# Protect files in folder on hosting linux using codeigniter php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting, .htpasswd

Im doing a little application write in php with codeigniter hosted in hostinglinux
i had no problems with create codeigniter interface with user login to access the application

now i have a problem...
i want to create some folder for the user to store some .pdf file like this picture
[image]

what can i do to protect every single users folder with the same password to login in the codeigniter application ?
my idea/goal is

username:user_a
pass:pass_user_a

for displayng the files in the folder of user_a (that is on hosting linux) the user must insert the password

anyone can help me ? sorry for the baddest english ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a solution in the following link which use CI framework and session to protect each user file:

[Solution for document protection with session in CodeIgniter](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-70243.html)